# JiBX binding DTD schema in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, binding, dtd, jibx

I have warnings in binding xml files:

```
No grammar constraints (DTD or XML schema) detected for the document.
```

I have done as is written in the answer here: [JiBX: How do I keep using interfaces in my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982263/jibx-how-do-i-keep-using-interfaces-in-my-code) (answer which is not accepted). But now I have an error in binding xml file:

```
Referenced file contains errors (file:/C:/Amplio/LiveCliq/Work/core/src/main/resources/config/rest/
```

mappings/binding.dtd). For more information, right click on the message in the Problems View and 
 select "Show Details..."

And the details are:

```
The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed. line 20
```

I am not familiar with DTD schemas, so I don't know what is the problem. Did anybody found the solution?

And - I do not want to turn off validation in XML files, I would like to have this in binding files (mainly for code assist and validation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added:

```
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//JIBX//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN" "http://jibx.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/*checkout*/jibx/core/docs/binding.dtd">
```

On top of XML binding document and it works.